# How parse such string in the python 3 to convert hex character already present in string with `\\x`

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, hex

Example.

```
x = "\\x20Please\\x20try\\x20again\\x20later"

y = parse_string(x)

print(y)
## It should be converted to "Please try again later".
```

I have tried the unquote method of URLDecoder. I have tried to encode("utf-8") but there doesn't work. I am thinking of find and replace incase there is no standard function available to handle these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first convert it back to a byte object - for that you encode it using a "charmap encoding": i.e. an encoding that can provide a "roundtrip" of any 0-256 codepoint char to bytes and back again. "latin1" is such an encoding.

And then, use the special "unicode escape" character codec to decode the result back to text - that will parse the "physical" `\\` characters as part of an escape code, like what takes place when the string is parsed in source code.

Sorry if it sounds complicated - in practice it is a lot simpler:

```py
In [40]: x = "\\x20Please\\x20try\\x20again\\x20later"                                                    

In [41]: y = x.encode("latin1").decode("unicode escape")                                                  

In [42]: print(y)         
 Please try again later
```

Comment: Thanks, @jsbueno this is helpful.